# How to manage page--front.tpl.php images from back-end/admin-panel in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a website in drupal 7, I have created a Home page in `page--front.tpl.php` with `Static Html` like the code below,

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-24 botmboxes">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="boxbotmimg">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./sites/all/themes/korhanifashion/images/PlasticRug-Boat.png">
                  <span class="hovblck"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="botboxhov">
                  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>limited_offers">
                    <img class="bbres" src="./sites/all/themes/korhanifashion/images/limroffer.png"></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-24 botmboxes botboxthree">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="boxbotmimg">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./sites/all/themes/korhanifashion/images/AnchorLine_BLCR_HI.png">
                  <span class="hovblck"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="botboxhov">
                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KORHANIhome">
                    <img class="bbres" src="./sites/all/themes/korhanifashion/images/fusonfbok.png"></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I want to manage these Images from back-end i.e from `Admin-panel`. So that Admin can change the images from `Admin-panel`, And also how Admin can put links to that images from back-end.
How I can do that?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve similar issues(customizing the dynamic home page contents) by creating a custom content type(https://www.drupal.org/node/306792).

And then you can hard-code to read nodes of a specific type in your template file or use Views (https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Added sample code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'home_image')
      ->entityCondition('status', 1);
$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $img_url = file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
    }
}
```

In the above code, 'home_image' is the name of content type you have created and 'field_image' is the name of image field. You can add and edit the name of image field when editing fields of content type. Please be sure to set the field type to 'Image'.

Comment: Is there any way just creating a content type and insert some php code in image section so that when enter image into content type the image should displays on where the php code is inserted.

Comment: In your template, you can load nodes of the custom content type you just created using EntityFieldQuery(https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708). It returns the list of nids. Load node objects with node_load_multiple() and you can get the url of images with file_create_url(): file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri]);

Comment: please post some sample code or edit my code posted, Thankyou

Comment: Thankyou very much I am trying this out, where should i put this code and $img_url is pasted like that i think src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>"

Comment: You can put the code in your template file, page--front.tpl.php, and yes, echo $img_url inside <img> 'src' attribute.

Comment: one thing more brother as i have about 5 images on the front page so for every one i have to write this code, is there any why just one code can handle all images?

Comment: Run the above code once and store the image URLs in an array, and you can refer to them later when you need to set the 'src' attribute of <img> tags.

Comment: and what about the click links on it?

Comment: You may add another field to your content type called 'link' or whatsoever (it can be of 'Text' type) and read its value just like you did with your image field: $node->field_link['und'][0]['safe_value'];